# RichTextEditor for silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

Is there any editor control in Silverlight 4?

I just want the basic functionality; much what Stackoverflow has while posting question. The basic stuff like making it bold, italic, etc. I saw Telerik's editor control. However, I'd rather not use it because it is a very large assembly of 1 MB. After already adding a few of Telerik's assemblies, my XAP size is above 2 MB.

Comment: Is this for a public facing website or an intranet?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones :- It is public facing website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered just using code around the built in RichTextBox?

Download sample from the MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926(v=VS.95).aspx.

Something to consider though is what ultimately you want to do this this Rich text?  The built in control use Xaml to describe the rich text which isn't much use to you if ultimately you need to expose it in an email.

Comment: - I want to allow the user to select text and allow to make them bold and italic and insert linebreaks. Is this possible with built in rich text control?

Comment: - Finally i created a user control and encapsulated all the logic in it based on my needs. Though, i am still wondering why was this logic not encapsulated when they shipped the toolkit. What do you think? Any specific reasons?

Comment: @Kar: The existing editor in the sample has many issues that need addressing if it were to be treated seriously.  It would not be trivial chunk of code and therefore would come with some cost.  The fact that bullet/numbered lists are not supported and its Xaml only nature would seriously limit its benefit.  So at a guess I would say the MS have decided it doesn't reach a threshold of benefit to cost ratio that would make it worthwhile.